# Handle back press with ShowcaseView

Tags: android, showcaseview

How can I handle a user pressing the back button, whilst a ShowcaseView is showing? I want to be able to hide the ShowcaseView when they press back.

*As linked from* https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView/issues/376

Answer (score 1):

ShowcaseView allows you to query if it is showing or not. So, if a user presses back and it is showing, simply hide it using [`Activity#onBackPressed()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed()):

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (sv.isShowing()) {
        sv.hide();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // in if condition check showcaseview is show or hide
        if(isShowcaseViewShow==true) {
           // here hide your showcase view
        }
        else{
              // here perform back action if view already hide
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
```